# Trying to remove a letter from a string in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to remove a character from a string in Python 3. The following is my code:

```
#Function that removes a character from a string
def removeChar(character, string):
    new_string = string.replace(character, "")

print(removeChar("e", "Hello World"))
```

However, the output of this program is just `None`. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: because you are not returning the `new_string` value ...

Comment: add `return new_string` at the end of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return `new_string` after your own function as follow:

```
def removeChar(character, string):
    new_string = string.replace(character, "")
    return new_string

print(removeChar("e", "Hello World"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Well if a function does not `return` anything, the Python interpreter will let it return `None`. So you should state:

```
def removeChar(character, string):
     return string.replace(character, "")
```

Furthermore you do not really **remove a character from the string**, strings are **immutable**, you create a copy of the string, where the character is missing compared to the given string.